# Breaking up api calls into smaller React components

Tags: reactjs

I have a quick React architecture question. I am making a social media type website and I have a Dashboard page. Since it is a homepage of sorts it contains different info retrieved from a few different api calls. I just started putting the logic for calling and rendering the api information into their own smaller components. Then I am importing the components into the Dashboard component and returning <"SubComponentOne" /> in the return of the Dashboard.

Is this an acceptable way of breaking down components? I felt that the Dashboard was getting to be very long, but I wasn't sure if the api calls should be at a higher level.

Thank you.

Comment: The concept of breaking down components is good but you can gather all your api calls into one seperate folder called Services and manage your api calls in there. by this way you have much cleaner workflow. if one problem occurs in your api call you can easily know where to find out but if you write it in each component you need time to find where it is.

Comment: @Ehsan so do you mean placing all the api calls in one file? Or in different files? Im not sure how that differs from what I proposed. Also, would they reside in their own class?

Comment: i said it is much cleaner to put all service apis into one file but from the point of performance it would not differ